# when launching application through link from SMS, the URIs keep getting cut

Tags: android

I'm doing a project, and I'm trying to launch our application through link from a received message. 
But the URIS keep getting cut... I don't know the reason why.
Here is the SMS I got - I can't upload pictures, so i'll make the link part bold.

test **com.wekimi.and**roid

I defined the URI in EmergencyActivity.java like this :

```
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("com.wekimi.android");
```

And I added intent-filter in manifest file like this :

```
    <activity android:name="EmergencyActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/> 
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data android:scheme="com.wekimi.android" />
 </intent-filter>
```

What would be the problem? I don't even know if the Uri is recognizing the scheme data or not, because it's too short so it can't be directed to a right destination.

Comment: You seem to be mixing up schemes and hosts. Your `intent-filter` is looking for `com.wekimi.android://....` URIs. The cut probably happens because ".and" is a TLD, while ".android" is not. Define a correct scheme. See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html and http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/filters.html for more information.

Comment: Thank you! I read the pages.  But I just realized.. that URI is going to be included in a message which will be opened through default message app, and we can't touch the code for the message app. Then isn't it not possible to make the link execute certain action? Would that have to be accepted by MNO or something?

Comment: I have a message that I got one day, in which there was a bit.ly link. It was sent to a browser app(the link was extend to a much longer url, such as XXX.XX.XX.XX/~tmpUser/XXX.html?blahblah...), and then a certain app was launched right after. I want to make my application be launched like that, but I don't understand exactly how I should do it...

Comment: They probably had a redirect on that bit.ly link to a registered scheme. Not sure if all browsers will allow you to redirect to a custom scheme without actually clicking a link, but try. Try opening a custom URL where there's 1. A Location redirect, 2. A `location.href` redirect, 3. A link. Make sure you register your filter correctly, and it works with at least 3, before trying 2 and 1. Then have that URL SMSed. There shouldn't be a limit on how long the link is, but since it's an SMS, they probably shortened it due to lack of space.